# How to pass parameters to a .msg file?

Tags: email, batch-file, outlook, autohotkey, msg

I have found how to send parameters to the outlook.exe file to create a new message, add an address, a subject, and a body of text:

Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\outlook.exe" /c ipm.note /m emailaddress@server.com;&;subject=Subject&body=Body_Of_Text

Now I am curious if I can do the same thing, but to a .msg file. I have a .msg file that will already have the subject and address embedded in it, but I need to figure out if I can pass the body of text into the file when it's opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better served by creating a standalone MSG file using an [MSG Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32899/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-C) such as [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/download.htm) or purchase a commercial license for something like [Mailbee.NET](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/email-components). Numerous other options exist, but once you have created the MSG, you can [open it via Outlook using the `/f` parameter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-HP001003110.aspx).

`Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\outlook.exe" /f "C:\Downloads\myCustomMessage.msg"`

Comment: I might look into this, however I am attempting to use the call with AutoHotKeys and have had issues calling outlook.exe from machine to machine so I'm trying to just open the msg file which will open in the default program.